# Angular 8 app compilation shows : "error TS1005: ':' expected "

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Hi I am developing an angular 8 app by watching a tutorial, In my header component I want the email id of the user who is currently logged in.My auth.service.ts is given below:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.auth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.auth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.auth.authState;
  }
  signOut() {
    return this.auth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

and my header.component.ts is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "src/app/services/auth.service";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./header.component.css"],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  email:string = null;
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
    auth.getUser().subscribe((user)=>{
      console.log("User is:",user);
      this.email = user?.email;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  async handSignOut(){
    try {
      await this.auth.signOut();
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/signin");
      this.toastr.info("Logout sucess");
      this.email = null;
    } catch (error) {
      this.toastr.error("Problem in Signout");
      
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile the code it is showing:

```
ERROR in src/app/layout/header/header.component.ts:20:25 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

20       this.email = user?.email;
                           ~
src/app/layout/header/header.component.ts:20:31 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

20       this.email = user?.email;
                                 ~
```

When I remove the "?" in line: this.email = user?.email; it is compiling successfully. How can I address this issue?

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "travelgram",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "browser-image-resizer": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.15.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.7",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "<0.900 || ^0.900.0-0 || ^9.0.0-0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.12.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need TypeScript 3.7 for this syntax to work, but you only have 3.5. Try upgrade your TypeScript version.

Comment: @SiddharthS Yes, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CyrilGandon Thank you so much for the update, I was unaware about the version requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
this.email = user ? user.email ? user.email :"Email Null" : "User Null";
```

or

```
if(user != null && user!= undefined)
{
  if(user.email != null && user.email != undefined)
   {
    this.email = user.email;
   }
}
```

or

```
if( (user != null && user!= undefined) && (user.email != null && user.email != undefined))
{
    this.email = user.email;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the usage of the ".?" expression, it only checks if the "user" value is null or undefined. If it is it would return undefined. So I guess the usage of this expression in your case might be redundant. If the user value should indeed be null or undefined you will get undefined independently of the ".?" expression.

Maybe this can give you further information:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: Thank you , The link helped.